# How to get multiple same tag text in a single variable in XML Processing Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, xml, xml-parsing

```
<PREAMB>
        <AGENCY TYPE="S">HOMELAND SECURITY </AGENCY>
        <AGENCY TYPE="O">LABOR</AGENCY>
        <AGY>
          <HD SOURCE="HED">AGENCY:</HD>
          <P>U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services</P>
        </AGY>
</PREAMB>
```

How can I get this as -
'departments are' : 'HOMELAND SECURITY,LABOR : U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services '

The below code is just returning -
'departments are' : 'LABOR : U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services'

```
for agency in preambl.findall("./PREAMB/AGENCY"):
    departments = agency.text
     if departments != '' or departments != None:
     if pre.findall("./PREAMB/AGY"):
            agency1 = ''
            for agencies in pre.findall("./PREAMB/AGY/P"):
                for para1 in agencies.itertext():
                    agency1 += para1.replace('\n', ' ')
            agency1 = ' '.join(agency1.split())
            if agency1:
                agency1 = '{"departments are":"' + str(departments) + ' : ' + str(agency1) + '"}'
            agency1 = json.loads(agency1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's no code in there to capture details in `AGENCY TYPE`

Answer (score 0):

You are making this a bit too complicated, I believe. Try it this way:

```
targets = ['.//AGENCY','.//AGY//P']
agencies = []
for target in targets:
    agencies.extend([agency.text for agency in preambl.findall(f'{target}')])
print('agencies are: ',agencies)
```

And see if you get your expected output.